# Jmeter test with thread startup delay doesnt end

Tags: jmeter

I am running Jmeter test with 3 thread groups. And, i have 3rd thread group with thread lifetime specified in order to specify startup delay. This had worked fine earlier but, now i see that the the test doesnt end at all. I have set debug logs but, no specific error. Any suggestions?

I thought the issue was with thread lifetime and tried to adjust the same. But, didnt help.

[Thread-Lifetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP8r8.png)

I found from existing posts that there is bug in Jmeter 5.4 and suggetion to use 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, in JMeter 5.4.1 the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with duration and start up delay set as per your scenario works fine.

[image]

One of possible reasons I can think of is that JMeter waits for response from the server and in case of [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers there is no default timeout (unless it's specified by underlying JRE and/or operating system)

So I would recommend double-checking your script and specify reasonable timeout values for Samplers, in case of HTTP Request samplers you can do it in "one shot" using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults), the setting lives under "Advanded" tab

[image]

Comment: i realize that this was because there was no data for the no. of users that were set. I am using inter communication preprocessor in 2 thread groups. Looks like that data is consumed from one thread group and removed and nothing left for the next thread group. looks like i should use jsr223 pre-processor to get values from queue instead.